# automation FTP file location

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, ftp

I'm trying to create an automation to fetch a CSV from the FTP and populate a Data Extension.

After the File Drop and setting up the Path from the FTP import folder to the correct file name I use the Import File option from Activities and on the Import File step when I try to choose my File Location the folders from there don't match the folders that I have in my FTP as I thought it should.

When I populate the File Naming Pattern with the name of the file I get "No file matching this File Naming Pattern currently exists in the File Location.
If run now, this Import activity would fail."

I can not find anywhere in the FTP or anywhere else the File Location structure that I have in the drop down menu.

Does anyone know where is the path for it?

Please find attached a couple of screenshots to make it understand better. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking into "ExactTarget Enhanced FTP Import"?

Comment: It does show me the folder but when I click on it I still get the same error.

Comment: I have updated my post with a third picture. The folder that contains the CSV file is recommendations and because I can't select it from ExactTarget Enhanced FTP Import, I still get the same error

Comment: Can you try organizing it so that the file gets dropped and picked from the Import folder? Also, you can use a wildcard instead of hardcoding the dates

Comment: yes, I can do that, thanks @zuzannamj I'm just curious where did all the folders come from because I can't find any sense there